# Set fill-opacity of various paths to 0 on an SVG file through XSLT

Tags: svg, xslt

I would like to set the fill opacity of all paths whose id starts with *Invisible* to 0.0, below the SVG.

**Original SVG (extract)**

```
<g id="Section-svg">

<path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" stroke="rgb(100, 100, 100)" style="fill: rgb(100, 100, 100); stroke-width: 0.3; stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-linecap: round; stroke rgb(100, 100, 100);"/>

<g id="symbols-svg">
<g id="Invisible2-svg" transform="translate(250, 90)" >
<path d="M-5 0a5 5 0 1 0 10 0 5 5 0 1 0-10 0Z" stroke="rgb(200, 200, 200)" id="Invisible2" style="fill: rgb(0, 15, 60); stroke-width: 1; fill-opacity: 0.9; stroke-opacity: 0.5; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke: rgb(0, 50, 100);" />
</g>

<g id="Invisible3-svg" transform="translate(250, 90)" >
<path d="M-5 0a5 5 0 1 0 10 0 5 5 0 1 0-10 0Z" stroke="rgb(200, 200, 200)" id="Invisible3" style="fill: rgb(0, 15, 60); stroke-width: 1; fill-opacity: 0.9; stroke-opacity: 0.5; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke: rgb(0, 50, 100);" />
</g>

</g>
</g>
```

Here is the XSL I used , I tried editing what I could find at [How to modify a SVG attribute using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56733293/how-to-modify-a-svg-attribute-using-xslt)

**XSL for the relative task**

```
 <xsl:template match="svg:*[@id[starts-with(., 'Invisible')]]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="fill-opacity">0.0</xsl:attribute> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Yet I only get the wanted paths duplicated, and with *fill-opacity* not as a style but as something that does not have real effect on the path.

**Resulting (wrong) SVG**

```
<g id="Section-svg">

<path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" stroke="rgb(100, 100, 100)" style="fill: rgb(100, 100, 100); stroke-width: 0.3; stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-linecap: round; stroke rgb(100, 100, 100);"/>

<g id="symbols-svg">
<g id="Invisible2-svg" transform="translate(250, 90)" >
<path d="M-5 0a5 5 0 1 0 10 0 5 5 0 1 0-10 0Z" stroke="rgb(200, 200, 200)" id="Invisible2" style="fill: rgb(0, 15, 60); stroke-width: 1; fill-opacity: 0.9; stroke-opacity: 0.5; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke: rgb(0, 50, 100);" fill-opacity="0.0;" />
</g>

<g id="Invisible3-svg" transform="translate(250, 90)" >
<path d="M-5 0a5 5 0 1 0 10 0 5 5 0 1 0-10 0Z" stroke="rgb(200, 200, 200)" id="Invisible3" style="fill: rgb(0, 15, 60); stroke-width: 1; fill-opacity: 0.9; stroke-opacity: 0.5; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke: rgb(0, 50, 100);" fill-opacity="0.0;" />
</g>
</g>
</g>
```

**Wanted result SVG**

```
<g id="Section-svg">

<path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" stroke="rgb(100, 100, 100)" style="fill: rgb(100, 100, 100); stroke-width: 0.3; stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-linecap: round; stroke rgb(100, 100, 100);"/>
<g id="symbols-svg">

<g id="Invisible2-svg" transform="translate(250, 90)" >
<path d="M-5 0a5 5 0 1 0 10 0 5 5 0 1 0-10 0Z" stroke="rgb(200, 200, 200)" id="Invisible2" style="fill: rgb(0, 15, 60); stroke-width: 1; fill-opacity: 0.0; stroke-opacity: 0.5; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke: rgb(0, 50, 100);" />
</g>

<g id="Invisible3-svg" transform="translate(250, 90)" >
<path d="M-5 0a5 5 0 1 0 10 0 5 5 0 1 0-10 0Z" stroke="rgb(200, 200, 200)" id="Invisible3" style="fill: rgb(0, 15, 60); stroke-width: 1; fill-opacity: 0.0; stroke-opacity: 0.5; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke: rgb(0, 50, 100);" />
</g>
</g>
</g>
```

I also tried matching the path and giving it the style I would like it to have

**XSL**

```
 <xsl:template match="svg:path[@id[starts-with(., 'Invisible')]]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
<path style="fill: rgb(0, 15, 60); stroke-width: 0.1; fill-opacity: 0.0; stroke-opacity: 0.0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke: rgb(0, 50, 100);">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

but both NotePad++ and VBA said the resulting XSL is not well formed.

Nor did this work

**XSL**

```
 <xsl:template match="svg:*[@id[starts-with(., 'Invisible')]]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute style="fill-opacity">0.0</xsl:attribute> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Could someone please advise?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the expected result. Reducing the example to only what's necessary to demonstrate the problem would also be helpful - see: [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a refinement of Michael's answer, which will work correctly even if the element has no existing `style` attribute, or has a `style` attribute which doesn't already contain a `fill-opacity` property.

It works slightly differently in that it has a template that matches an *element* whose `id` attribute starts with `Invisible`, rather than directly matching the `style` attribute of such an element.

The template copies the "invisible" element, and its attributes, and then constructs a new `style` attribute that starts with `fill-opacity:0.0;`, and then finishes in one of two different ways: if there was an existing `style` containing a `fill-opacity` property, then it copies the parts before and after that `fill-opacity` property, but otherwise it copies the entire value of the `style` attribute.

The reason for doing it in two different ways is that the functions `substring-before` and `substring-after` will return empty strings if the substring being sought (i.e. `fill-opacity:` is not in the string, and that would have the effect of erasing all the other CSS properties in the `style` attribute.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(@id, 'Invisible')]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="style">
                <xsl:text>fill-opacity: 0.0;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(@style, 'fill-opacity')">
                        <!-- style already contains a fill-opacity property, so
                        it's safe to use substring-before and substring-after to 
                        extract the preceding and following CSS properties -->
                        <xsl:value-of select="
                            concat(
                                substring-before(
                                    @style, 
                                    'fill-opacity:'
                                ),
                                substring-after(
                                    substring-after(
                                        @style, 
                                        'fill-opacity:'
                                    ), 
                                    ';'
                                )
                            )
                        "/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <!-- style had no existing fill-opacity property
                        so just copy the whole text including any other CSS properties -->
                        <xsl:value-of select="@style"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I am guessing correctly, you want to change the existing `fill-opacity` value inside the existing `style` attribute. If so, try something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="svg:*[starts-with(@id, 'Invisible')]/@style">
    <xsl:attribute name="style">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., 'fill-opacity:')" />
        <xsl:text>fill-opacity: 0.0;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(., 'fill-opacity:'), ';')" />
    </xsl:attribute> 
</xsl:template> 
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think this is not quite right; if the existing `@style` attribute value does not already contain a `fill-opacity` property then this code will successfully add a `fill-opacity: 0.0;` property but discard any other CSS properties. If the existing `@style` doesn't contain `fill-opacity` then the new property can just be prepended to the existing value of `@style`.

Comment: @ConalTuohy As I said at the beginning, this is intended to change an **existing** `fill-opacity` value.

Comment: Yes it will change an existing fill-opacity value, but it has a bug that means it won't work correctly if the existing style attribute has no fill-opacity.

Comment: @ConalTuohy Indeed it won't work as expected if the stated assumption is not true. What is your point?

Comment: I'm just pointing out that since the stated assumption may not actually hold, this code may cause the loss of formatting if that assumption is violated. A version that didn't make that assumption would be safer. That's my point.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two `xsl:copy` elements inside the template that matches "Invisible" elements; hence the duplication. You want to copy the element *once*, copy its attributes, then create the new `fill-opacity` attribute, then apply templates to copy child nodes (and descendants, recursively).

Try this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    exclude-result-prefixes="svg"
    version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="svg:*[@id[starts-with(., 'Invisible')]]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="fill-opacity">0.0</xsl:attribute> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> 
  
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

BTW your well-formedness error is because your SVG `path` element is not closed.

Comment: thank you, I corrected a bit the code for the SVG and I double checked the syntax for `path`  at https://css-tricks.com/svg-path-syntax-illustrated-guide/ and I see that it is self-closing `<path d=" ...."/>`, so the above should be correct. I tried your solution but it appends `fill-opacity="0.0"` at  the end of the path like the above (without duplication) without setting the opacity to 0.0.
`<path d="..." stroke="rgb(200, 200, 200)" id="Invisible3" style="same as above" fill-opacity="0.0"/>`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "... at the end of the path"? The code above creates a `fill-opacity` attribute with the value `0.0`, which should have the desired effect. Does it not? See https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/painting.html#FillOpacityProperty

Comment: I think I see the problem now; you have existing `style` attributes which already contain a `fill-opacity` property. You'll need to parse that attribute and remove or replace the existing property value.

Comment: NB a "self-closing" element needs to have `/>` at the end of the tag, rather than just `>`

Comment: The above does have the slash`/>`  I found at  https://xsl-list.mulberrytech.narkive.com/RwD0Jc0n/is-it-possible-to-rewrite-part-of-an-attribute-value-with-xsl `<xsl:attribute name="style">
<xsl:text>stroke-width</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@style,'stroke-width')"/>
</xsl:attribute>` for XSL 1.0. but I would not know how to use it since I see no place where to enter another value. I will try your solution and let you know. Thank you for taking the time to look into this.